# Log form and TinyMCE changes

Tags: jquery, forms, tinymce

Hi I am trying to log changes made in a form, so that a user can be informed they have unsaved changes before leaving the current page.

I am using a simple method by giving all form fields a class of .X and I have a hidden field called changed and I use the following code to listen for changes and update changed

```
$(".X").change(function() {
    $('#changed').val(1);
});
```

However in my form I've got a TinyMCE textarea which I have added the following

```
setup : function(e) {
    e.onChange.add(function() {
    $('#changed').val(1);
});
```

For some reason that I can not find an answer too this onChange function for tinymce does not take effect unless at least two changes have been made.

Thank you in advance for any help that you may provide.